# Try to Queue laravel Supervisor error

Tags: laravel, queue, supervisord

I try with chown with www-data and chmod 777 to worker.log is still return

```
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_00: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_06: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_02: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_03: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_04: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_05: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_07: ERROR (spawn error)
laravel-worker:laravel-worker_01: ERROR (spawn error)
```

Comment: did you find the issue.?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable the log file, then check that, may be you are passing any invalid parameter or may be you didn't pass the correct system username.

Comment: i am getting this error in this worker log 
[UnexpectedValueException]                                                   
  The stream or file "/var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel-2017-07-  
  24.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: Currently your Storage directory do not has write permission, give read/write permission to your storage. It will start work

Comment: i have given it using Chmood 777 but when ever new log file is created each day then that log file does not have 777 it has 644 permission i think

Comment: try this, chmod 777 -R ./storage/

Comment: i have tried it but still the new log which is created today on logs folder is showing 644 permission

Comment: Thanks for this. Doing `chmod 777 -R ./storage/` worked for me